# tabulary and multirow

Tags: tables

I want to create a very basic table with two columns. The second column should be made of one single cell (multirow). However, the text does not adjust to this single cell. Here's my code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ | l J |}
\hline
cell1 & \cellcolor{lightgray} \\
cell2 & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}single cell}\\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Could someone teach me how to make the text fit in the single cell?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How the text should be text adjusted in `multicolumn` cell? Also please extend your code snippet to complete small document with your table, which we can test as it is.

Comment: I would like that the text fit in the "single cell" as a multiline text, respecting the page width (that's why I am using tabulary). As it is now, it is displayed as a single line text not bounded to the cell limits.

Comment: (i) your table is text wide (ii) second `J` column in `tabulary` can be extent to the right border of text, so in your table is not meet the  condition for automatic break of text into two lines since in cell is enough space for one line text! And please again, provide complete small document, as I already ask you.

Comment: I've already edited the original post with the small document. Should I replace J for which letter? With L or R, the problem still persists.

Comment: Thank you, Zarko. It seems that substituting the {*} parameter by {=} solves the width issue. However, if the text is too long, it will still overflow the cell height. How could I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to add empty rows in the first column or make rows higher.

Answer (score 2):

- Use option `=` for `multirow` cell. In this case, the cell width will be equal to column width
- `tabulary` table environment adopt columns of type `L`, `R`, `C` and `J` to the width of cells content so that table width will be smaller or equal to the prescribed table width
- height (or number of text lines) in `multirow` cell must be smaller or equal to the height (or number of text lines) of spanned rows in other columns.

An MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{multirow, tabulary}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ | l >{\columncolor{lightgray}}J |}
    \hline 
cell1 & \\
cell2 & \multirow{-2}{=}{single cell single cell single cell single cell single cell single cell single cell single}\\ 
    \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)